# Manipulating/Replacing values in dictionaries within lists

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

My data looks similar to the data shown below ('snippet.json'). I want to be able to replace values for example, for id:1, replace employee number to 2455.

Data Snippet:

> {"employees": [{"level1":{"id":1, "firstname": "John", "employee
>   number": 2343 },{"level1":{"id":2, "firstname": "Jane", "employee
>   number": 5647 }}]}

I understand that it is much easier to replace values when in the form of a list or a dictionary, so I did the following to convert it to a list.

```
import json
viewer_string=open('snippet.json','r')

data_str = viewer_string.read()

data_list = []
data_list.append(data_str)
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Is there anyway I could convert Snippet.json into a dictionary? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: That json doesn't quite look valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are importing json, you might want to do something like below,

```
json_data = json.loads(viewer_string.read())
```

you have your data in dict type and you can loop through and replace values as you wish. Make sure the file has valid json